# Is there a way to abort execution when vars file is missing?

Tags: ansible

I would like to wrap the following with something that stops execution when the file is missing:

```
  vars_files:
    - "{{ customer }}.yml"
```

Not sure if there is something like that in Ansible (2.4).

Comment: I guess this will do it. I was wondering if I could wrap it and have some nicer error message. This will do it for now thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything ― if the file is missing Ansible stops by default. Example:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml --extra-vars customer=non_existing_file
```

produces the following error and stops the execution:

> ERROR! vars file {{ customer }}.yml was not found

---

I suspect your `customer` variable is not set in the scope to be used in `vars_files` declaration, so use [`include_vars` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/include_vars_module.html) instead:

```
- hosts: all
  pre_tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: "{{ customer }}.yml"
```

By default it produces an error if `customer` is undefined:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'customer' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/Users/techraf/so48065296-is-there-a-way-to-abort-execution-when-vars-file-is-missing/playbook.yml': line 8, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n    - include_vars:\n      ^ here\n\nexception type: \nexception: 'customer' is undefined"}

---

If you are unhappy with the error message itself, you can prepend it with a task using [`assert`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/assert_module.html) or [`fail`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/fail_module.html).

Comment: Thanks, this will in fact stop when the variable is missing. I was wondering how to stop when the file is missing.